# XCode7 Core Data: Fetch for objects etc

Tags: ios, core-data, xcode7

I created an iOS8 application and updated it to XCode7. I have a couple of problems after I recreated the NSManagedObject.

First I get an error, if I fetch for contacts and iterate over them:

```
let contacts = try self.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(request) as! [Contact]

for contact in contacts{
//--> EXC_BAD_INSTRUCION
}
```

Contact is my NSManagedObject. I do not get any compiler error or warning.

Second: I get this warning:

```
CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named 'MyAppName.Contact' for entity 'Contact'.  Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead.
```

What can cause this? The @objc(Contact) in Contact has already been generated bei XCode and now I can't set the className MyAppName.Contact in CoreData-editor. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found it. All the other tips are not working, because Apple has changed it with XCode7.

Now XCode creates `@(Classname)` in the NSManagedSubclass. This needs to be commented out (beta1 and beta2). Then XCode can find your class.